# Increment while loop on success of asynchronous google.script.run

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to use [google.script.run, the asynchronous client-side JavaScript API provided by Google Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) within a while loop. I understand that calls to google.script.run are asynchronous so I even tried using a global variable 'window.i' for loop iterations.

Unfortunitely window.i++ never happens and the browser freezes when I run this code.

Here's the code snippet that I am struggling with:

```
var iterations = 5;
window.i = 0;
while (window.i < iterations) {
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(){
        window.i++;
     })
     .sendNow();
}
```

Is there any way I can increment the loop variable on success callback?

Comment: Why do you want it async success handler? why not increment it in outside and in while loop? since while loop will not wait for async success callback. it will just keep on execute the loop eventually your browser will hang up

Comment: @kumkanillam that will just fire all requests at once. It is important for sendNow() to be sequential; as in process only remaining records after the first run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the success handler to send the next request. Dont use a while loop.

```
//these dont have to be global
var i = 0;
var iterations = 5;
function send() {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function() {
    i++;
    if (i < iterations) {
      send();
    }
  })
  .sendNow();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am currently running out of quota so cant test this. Will do some tests with this approach by end of day and get back to you.

Comment: I tested it with `setTimeout`